# Scintillator for adjusting sputter gun lenses

Tags: experimental-physics, vacuum, experimental-technology

What do you use to adjust the beam of you sputter cannon?

We have a test plate with a scintillating coating, that is now almost completely worn out, and I would like to replace it, but I am unable to find out what the luminescent coating was, or any supplier of similar plates. Google was strangely devoid of results.

Does anyone have any pointers to either how to make a suitable UHV-compartible coating or where to procure a new test plate?

Comment: Quartz may work, depending on ion energy. Various rare-earth scintillators are used, but mostly are custom-made.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to use a tarnished (oxidized) copper plate, you will see the spot where the ions clean the surface by observing a color change.

other crystals that show luminescense from dopant atoms are commonly called "phosphors". You can find a few names here
http://www.proxivision.de/products/phosphor-screen.html

A common one would be YAG:Ce.